# Regex with Whitespace

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

I am try to write a regex to match the following:

```
act=MATCHME
act=Match me too
```

I have the following regex to match either one but not both. Here is my effort:

```
matches MATCHME: act=(\w+)
matches Match me too: (\w+\s\w+\s\w+)
```

Is there anyway to can combine the two with OR, or may I be looking at this wrong?

I am using the JAVA regex engine.

Comment: In regex "or" is `|`

Comment: Match against what? You can match against ". *" here, and that works for your two examples. And for anything else. So the part missing : examples of "should not match on"

Answer (score 2):

You may use an optional non-capturing group:

```
act=(\w+(?:\s+\w+\s+\w+)?)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eCuZ5p/1)

The `?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the quantified subpattern. When it is applied to a grouping construct, the quantification is applied to the whole *pattern sequence*, so `(?:\s+\w+\s+\w+)?` matches 1 or 0 sequences of 1+ whitespaces, 1+ word chars, 1+ whitespaces and again 1+ word chars.

You may further subsegment the pattern if you need to capture 2-word substrings after `act=`.

Comment: Also, the ?: operator (Elvis operator) is only used to say that this group must be considered in the matching process but not captured.

Comment: Yes, it does not create any additional `.group()`. Just groups subpatterns that must be matched as a sequence and make it possible to make a whole sequence of patterns optional (or repeat zero/one or more times with `*`/`+` quantifiers, or some exact number of times with `{x}` or x to y times with `{x,y}` quantifiers).

Answer (score 0):

Surely you know how to compose regular expressions by [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression may help you

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```